# Reverse geocoding

Tags: google-maps, google-app-engine, geocoding

I have a worker (servlet) called by a queue in google app engine.

I can call an external URI for reverse geocoding like: http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=51.0475&lon=3.5323&zoom=18&addressdetails=1

But when I try to call the "The Google Geocoding API" with/without the key parameter: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=51.0475,3.5323&sensor=false, I always get the following message: `Attempt to access a blocked recipient without permission. (mapped-IPv4)`

The billing is active, the key is also defined in the dev console,  and the URL with the key work in my browser but not from app engine.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I am getting the json data back on opening the link http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=51.0475,3.5323&sensor=false

Comment: Have you created a server API key? Also the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=en_US) says you should use https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters, I think maps.google.com is legacy.

Comment: i use the json as output parameter and i have also a key

Comment: I also get the data but when i open from outside the google app engine environment ...

Answer (score 0):

to avoid the issue, i don't use anymore the org.apache.http.client package but now i use the com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch package.

Now the URI to google also work

thanks